Flutter build error: "invalid source release: 17" when building app bundle
I'm encountering an issue while trying to build an Android app bundle (appbundle) for release in my Flutter project on Android studio. I'm getting the following error message:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':package_info_plus:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> error: invalid source release: 17

Here's some details of my setup:
Java Home:
/usr/libexec/java_home -V

Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    20.0.1 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 20.0.1" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-20.jdk/Contents/Home
    17.0.2 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "OpenJDK 17.0.2" /Users/user/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.0.2/Contents/Home
    1.8.391.13 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-20.jdk/Contents/Home

Environment Configuration (echo $JAVA_HOME):
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home

Flutter Version:
flutter --version 
Flutter 3.19.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 54e66469a9 (2 days ago) • 2024-04-17 13:08:03 -0700
Engine • revision c4cd48e186
Tools • Dart 3.3.4 • DevTools 2.31.1

Android Project Configuration (android/app/build.gradle):
android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    android {
        ndkVersion "25.2.9519653"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

I have been facing this issue after upgrading to macOS Sonoma 14.4.1, and I'm using an M3 Mac.
I've tried various solutions from stack overflow
Execution Failed for task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac in Android Studio
Could someone please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

done everything which where suggested below but nothing works

Here's how I resolved the issue

I ran the following command to gather detailed information:

    cd android
   ./gradlew assembleDebug --info


    What went wrong:
    A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
    > Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
    > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
      Your current JDK is located in /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
      You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing org.gradle.java.home in gradle.properties.


Locate Java installation directory on my computer by running the following command:
/usr/libexec/java_home -V

Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
 20.0.1 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 20.0.1" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-20.jdk/Contents/Home
 17.0.2 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "OpenJDK 17.0.2" /Users/user/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.0.2/Contents/Home
 1.8.391.13 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-20.jdk/Contents/Home


I found the path to Java 17 in the output:
/Users/user/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.0.2/Contents/Home


Then, I set the Java 17 path by adding the following line to the gradle.properties file in my Android project directory:
org.gradle.java.home=/Users/user/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.0.2/Contents/Home




These steps represent a valid approach to find and fix the issue. Thank you!

I encountered the same error on my Azure Pipeline. I fixed it by changing the JDK version.
I modified Java Tool Installer task:
- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs: 
    versionSpec: '11'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'

to the following:
- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs: 
    versionSpec: '17'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'


Fixed by updating Android Studio.

So in my experience, all the SO posts claim a resolution is to configure via Gradle/project settings OR via JAVA_HOME env variable. I found that I could open my flutter projects android folder and configure the Gradle JDK and have a successful build, but when opening the greater flutter project I still could not have a successful build.  All my configurations correctly pointed to the correct JDK, but when the flutter project would build it would still be stuck on the incorrect version! Finally I came across a random GitHub issue which referenced a "flutter config" command. This command contains information that seems to explain why everyone has to update Android studio in order to resolve the issue for flutter projects, specifically. If this setting is left unconfigured, the following precedence takes effect:
Default - JDK bundled with Android studio
THEN JAVA_HOME env variable
THEN directory containing java binary found in the users path


I have fixed this error with flutter config --jdk-dir /your/path/jvm/java-17-openjdk/
This is a global config and it changes the jdk for all of your projects. You can unset the config with flutter config --jdk-dir ''

Are you using two Java-related environment configurations in your '.zshrc' or '.bash_profile'?
Note: export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8) sets Java_home to Java 1.8 and export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.0.2/Contents/Home sets to OpenJDK 17, error maybe due to conflicting java version or configurations
you can resolve it by,
1 Check Java version using echo $JAVA_HOME make sure it uses Java 1.8 version
2 Update your Gradle Conf in your Android project's 'build.gradle' file, ensure that the 'compileOptions' and 'kotlinOptions' are set to use Java 1.8:
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

3 Remove Conflicting JAVA_HOME  Since there are two 'JAVA_HOME' configurations in your code remove or comment out the one that sets it to OpenJDK 17 in your '.zshrc' or '.bash_profile'
4 Restart Android studio

Thanks Vinutha, I tried above steps and restarted Android studio, but still same issue. I have now updated my question after trying out your solution. Can you please take a look?

@Gladiator set your JAVA_HOME
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-20.jdk/Contents/Home
Restart android studio and let me know if there's changes in the error or if it resolves

I downgraded my current java version from 21 to 17 and the problem was solved for me.
my app/build gradle
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
} 

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '17'
}

kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(17)
}

my gradle.properties
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk- 
17.0.11.jdk/Contents/Home

my gradle wrapper properties
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-all.zip

this does not work for me
getting this error: -  https://ibb.co/R9F3GCq


Download the Latest JDK 17
Update Android Studio to the latest Version
Select the JDK to 17 from file>project structure>SDKs and it will be resolved


what to do with vs code ?

I faced this issue when I rerun my app after a long time.
I resolved this error by adding this line into gradle.properties
org.gradle.java.home=/<path to your .jdks folder>/.jdks/corretto-17.0.11

This looks identical to Gladiator's answer.

I found the error is caused by the Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) version in the Flutter app, as defined in android/settings.gradle:
plugins {
......
id "com.android.application" version "8.1.0" apply false
......
}
The version "8.1.0" requires Java 17 to build, changing it to "7.0.0" will work with Java 8.

For those who are experiencing this issue on Github actions, try checking If JDK is installed and It's version with (Note that It checks if version is 17 apply changes for your needs) :
- name: Check java found
  id: check_java
  shell: bash
  run: |
    if java --version 2>&1 | grep -q "17"; then
        echo "installed=true" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
    else
        echo "installed=false" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
    fi

Also handle logic like this:
- name: Install java
  if: steps.check_java.outputs.installed == 'false'
  uses: actions/setup-java@v3
  with:
    distribution: "zulu"
    java-version: "17.x"
    cache: "gradle"


This issue occurs when a plugin requires JDK version 17 or higher, but your Flutter setup is using a lower JDK version.
You can check the JDK version Flutter is using with the following command:
flutter doctor -v
Check the output:

This is the JDK version Flutter is currently using. If it's lower than 17, you need to update Flutter's JDK version.

Download JDK 17 and configure the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to the path of JDK 17.
then verify it with the command:
javac --version

Reconfigure the JDK for Flutter with the command:
flutter config --jdk-dir=$JAVA_HOME

Verify again using: (You may need to restart your IDE to apply the changes).
flutter doctor -v


If the JDK version is now 17, congratulations! You have successfully updated the JDK.
